# A corollary of Dominated Convergence Theorem: If $\operatorname{plim} X_n = X, |X_n|<Y$, and $Y \in L_1, \implies EX_n \rightarrow EX$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

What I am confused about the premise: I understand that relaxed the condition of almost sure convergence in the original DCT and I guess $ Y \in L_1 $ is more strict condition than $EY < \infty$ However only thing my prof told us about a function being in $L_1$ space is that $Y$ is integrable, so I don't see any difference between the original condition, where $EY = \int_{\Omega} Y(\omega)d\mu(\omega)$

Meanwhile, I would like to approach this problem using the fact that

$\operatorname{plim} X_n = X \implies \forall \ \text{subsequence} \ X_{n_{k}}, \exists  \ \text{further subsequence} \ X_{n_{k_l}} \ \text{such that} \ X_{n_{k_l}} \rightarrow X$ almost surely, and apply the DCT for the $ X_{n_{k_l}} $, but I wonder if there is any caveats I should consider if I want to do the proof this way.

Hints for other more concise approaches would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your approach is just lovely. Also, you seem to misunderstand: In the theory of Lesbegue integration, for a general variable $Y$ (that attains both positive and negative values), $EY$ is not considered defined unless $E|Y|<\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

Prove by contradiction. First note that there is  a subsequence of $(X_n)$ converging a.s  to $X$ which implies $|X| \leq Y$ a.s.. Hence $E|X| <\infty$.

Now suppose $EX_n \to EX$ is false. Then there exists $\epsilon >0$ and a subsequence $(n_k)$ such that $|EX_{n_k}-EX| \geq \epsilon$ for all $k$ $\cdots$ (1). There a subsequence $(n_{k_j})$ of $(n_k)$ such that $X_{n_{k_j}} \to X$ a.s.. By DCT we get $EX_{n_{k_j}} \to EX$ which contradicts  (1).